# Struts 1 custom localization

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, struts1

I need some help with the following problem. We have an existing web application that uses no framework at all (just servlets) and we need to add new functionalities but instead of adding a new servlet to the `web.xml`, we are going to add Struts 1 along with Spring.

Since the project already exists, we have to configure Struts to be able to get along with the conventions already in place. One of those is localization.

Instead of using .property files, all localizable texts come from our database so I implemented my own **MessageResourcesFactory** and **MessageResources** classes. The problem is that in our application we get the user language from an Integer session attribute called **"LANGUAGE"** and not from the Locale attribute **"org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE"** that Struts uses by default.

The question is this. How do I tell Struts to fetch the user language from my custom Integer attribute instead of the stantard Locale attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no direct way to tell Struts to use another session attribute for using the locale. And even if Struts could do this, you'd need to implement a mapping between your custom integer and a "real" `Locale` object.

My suggestions:

- Implement your own `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener` which syncs the **LANGUAGE** attribute to the corresponding Struts locale attribute
- Or change the code where you set your **LANGUAGE** attribute to also set the Struts session attribute

Comment: I think this is the most appropiate solution since it attacks the problem directly, which in the end is to sync two session attributes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be setup a **filter** that will intercept the **LANGUAGE** and set the according Struts `Locale` before executiong the action:

```
public class localeFilter implements Filter  
{  

    public void destroy()  
    {  

    }  

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws Exception  
    {  
        // read the int LANGUAGE and set the Locale used by Struts
    }  

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException  
    {  

    }  

}
```

And declare the filter in web.xml:

```
  <filter>  
    <filter-name>localeFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>com.example.filters.MyFilter</filter-class>  
  </filter> 

  <filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>localeFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>  
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to extend the `ActionServlet` and override methods `doGet` and `doPost` to change the locale via putting it into request before the `process()`. Like

```
String locale = "your_locale";
request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, new Locale(locale));
```